# How to merge the multiple lists into a dict with Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm using Python to translate a txt file into JSON. However, when I was iterating the lines from txt, the result is containing multiple lists there, and I failed to merge the list into a dict with the function zip(). Can anyone help me figure it out? I've been stuck here for a couple of hours. Thanks.

```
 with open(path, encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    seq = re.compile("[|]")
    for line_num, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        result = seq.split(line.strip("\n"))
        print(result)
```

This is the output:

```
['Delivery', 'Customer Name', 'Shipment Priority', 'Creation Date', 'Customer Number', 'Batch Name', 'Release Date']
['69328624', 'Zhidi Feng', 'Standard Priority', '13-OCT-20', '432579', '19657423', '13-OCT-20 00:01:07']
['69328677', 'Zhengguo Huang', 'Standard Priority', '13-OCT-20', '429085', '19657425', '13-OCT-20 00:01:34']
```

Comment: Btw, in the response, the first list is the column name, which is supposed to be used as key, and the following values are the values.

Comment: Please update the question to show the expected output.

Comment: BTW, you should see if the built-in `csv` module can help you read and interpret the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that ?

```py
>>> lists = [["12", "Abc", "def"], ["34", "Ghi", "jkl"]]
>>> fields = ["id", "lastname", "firstname"]
>>> dicts = []
>>> for l in lists:
...     d = {}
...     for i in range(3):
...             d[fields[i]] = l[i]
...     dicts.append(d)
>>> dicts
[{'id': '12', 'lastname': 'Abc', 'firstname': 'def'}, 
{'id': '34', 'lastname': 'Ghi', 'firstname': 'jkl'}]
```

Edit: included in your existing code:

```py
    dicts = []
    for line_num, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        result = seq.split(line.strip("\n"))
        if line_num = 0:
            keys = result
        else:
            d = {}
            for i, key in enumerate(keys):
                d[key] = result[i]
            dicts.append(d)
```

(I didn't test this since I don't have the file you're using)

Comment: Recommend changing the `list` variable name to something else as it’s overwriting the builtin.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the notes, pretty much like that, but the weird thing is, the type of variable, result is not a list at all, it is more like a parallel set of list, let me give you something more, <class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>

Comment: ['Delivery', 'Customer Name', 'Shipment Priority', 'Creation Date', 'Customer Number', 'Batch Name', 'Release Date']  this is the very first column, and I wanna use it as the key in Dict, and ['69328624', 'Zhidi Feng', 'Standard Priority', '13-OCT-20', '432579', '19657423', '13-OCT-20 00:01:07'] ['69328677', 'Zhengguo Huang', 'Standard Priority', '13-OCT-20', '429085', '19657425', '13-OCT-20 00:01:34'] these are the coming up responses I wanna use as values in Dict.

Comment: It will be more straightforward if you can paste the response into Sublime Text and you will see the format is not the typical [[xx,yy], [ee,rr]]

Comment: replace fields with `data[0]` and lists with `data[1:]`

Comment: I've also tried to slice it, the funniest thing is, the response is sliced vertically instead of horizontally, let me give the response: Delivery
69328624
69328677

Comment: you mean to retrieve the data from the string ? maybe `json.loads("[" + data.replace("] [", "],[") + "]")`

Comment: I can see what you trying to achieve Marc, unfortunately, no, the result is not a string anyway

Comment: You'll need to give more info then

Comment: Sure, so, in your case, the data = result, and as you can see, the output of the result from my code is a multiple list, <class 'list'> <class 'list'> <class 'list'> <class 'list'>, and there is no way to use replace then.

Comment: Super! Marc! You are amazing! I  just realized the second layer of the enumerate is the king! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you can use zip for making a dictionary like this. (I separate keys and values in two lists.)

```py
with open(path, encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    seq = re.compile("[|]")
    lines = f.readlines()
    keys = lines[0] # stting keys
    dict_list = []
    for line_num, line in enumerate(lines[1:]):
        result = seq.split(line.strip("\n"))
        dict_list.append(dict(zip(keys, result))) # making a dict and append it to list
```

Comment: Hi Aref, thanks for your notes, yes, zip() is my ultimate goal but the current issue is that I failed to generate the two separate lists here. I wanna get the first list from my result as the Key, and the following as the Value.

Comment: check out the edited answer, I hope it could help you the best.

Comment: Yes Aref, once I read the code from Marc I realized how I was trapped in the function of list and lost myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> total
[['Delivery', 'Customer Name', 'Shipment Priority', 'Creation Date', 'Customer Number', 'Batch Name', 'Release Date'], ['69328624', 'Zhidi Feng', 'Standard Priority', '13-OCT-20', '432579', '19657423', '13-OCT-20 00:01:07'], ['69328677', 'Zhengguo Huang', 'Standard Priority', '13-OCT-20', '429085', '19657425', '13-OCT-20 00:01:34']]
>>> keys = total[0]
>>> 
>>> values = total[1:]
>>> wanted = [ dict(zip(keys, value)) for value in values]
>>> wanted
[{'Delivery': '69328624', 'Customer Name': 'Zhidi Feng', 'Shipment Priority': 'Standard Priority', 'Creation Date': '13-OCT-20', 'Customer Number': '432579', 'Batch Name': '19657423', 'Release Date': '13-OCT-20 00:01:07'}, {'Delivery': '69328677', 'Customer Name': 'Zhengguo Huang', 'Shipment Priority': 'Standard Priority', 'Creation Date': '13-OCT-20', 'Customer Number': '429085', 'Batch Name': '19657425', 'Release Date': '13-OCT-20 00:01:34'}]
```

Comment: Thanks ky! Your idea is also appreciated.